# Amazon MWS RequestReport API call do not work

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

We are calling `RequestReport` API in Amazon MWS Reports section, which always returns Response(400), with a message

> "Request for report type 1202 is not allowed at this time"

How to resolve this issue so the API call returns proper response with data.

Are we missing some steps? any other API needs to call or do we need to schedule request through other API? Please provide your inputs on this.

Comment: What report are you trying to request?  It must be one of the reports listed here: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

Comment: Try using Amazon MWS Scratchpad if it does the same thing https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: This is an old one, but did anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: Anyone found the solution same issues happening for SP-API with LWA.